# jQuery $.ajax not sending data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to send AJAX query after clicking a link, and PHP returns json, that I need to output in jQuery.
But I cannot find a mistake, `var_dump($_POST)` in php files returns empty array, and the main problem - why `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` returns GET?

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.js').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var item = $(this).html();

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        url: '/web/4/god/core/ajax.php',
        data: {article: item},
        success: function(result){
            $('.content').html(result.content);
        }
    });
});
```

});

ajax.php returns correct json object, but only if I use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`, and it's always "physics", so as I understood it means that PHP could not find my data that I send.

**ajax.php**

```
if (!empty($_GET['article'])) {
    $topic = $_GET['article'];
} else {
    $topic = 'physics';
}
$result = array();

$query = "SELECT `text` 
          FROM content 
          WHERE topic='" . $topic . "'";
if (!$query) {
    die("loh");
}
$get = mysql_query($query);
if (!$get) { 
    die (mysql_error());
}
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
    $result['topic'] = $topic;
    $result['content'] = htmlspecialchars($arr["text"],ENT_SUBSTITUTE);
}
$json = json_encode($result);
echo $json;
```

Thanx a lot!

P.S.
[Here it returns POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmVBh.png)

Comment: where is `$topic = $_POST['article'];` ?

Comment: Or use $_REQUEST so it be either GET or POST

Comment: Or use the much, much simpler jQuery functions like `get`, `post`, and `getJSON` rather than `ajax`.

Comment: @SimoneNigro i`ve tried with POST, but it didn't work at all. With GET at least it returns "physics" content, but $_POST is undefined

Comment: @JaredSmith I used post function, and request method still was GET

Comment: @ElyaKorobova What version of jQuery are you using?  Did you try adding the type: 'POST' option as outlined in the answer I posted below?

Comment: @ElyaKorobova When you say you tried with `POST`, did you also changed the PHP code so it used `$_POST` rather than `$_GET` on the first two lines? If you want the code to answer to `POST` and  `GET` you could use `$_REQUEST` variable on your PHP code

Comment: @KrisOye I use 2.1.4, and I added type POST as you said

Comment: @Piyin I returned to $_POST in that two lines, so now I've got undefined

Comment: @ElyaKorobova Since you are using jQuery > 1.9 then you're using the correct setting ('method').  'type' is now just an alias for method.  So you can disregard my answer.

Comment: @KrisOye oh, I won't) thank you for information

Comment: @ElyaKorobova I saw your picture, you see the part where it says `responseText` and it starts with `POST{`. I think that `POST` is messing with your JSON so jQuery cannot decode it, thus giving you `undefined`. Could you give us the PHP code you used when you changed `$_GET` with `$_POST`?

Comment: oh, there was POST before JSON because I've added one more echo with request method, now the situation is, I've changed $_GET to $_POST, and it even works if I put AJAX to browser console with any topic that I need, but if I click on the link nothing happens

Comment: Would be helpful if you post the <html> markup  you use to grab the data.